# Got Issue for Framework Laravel 5.3 with PHP ver 5.6.30 using backpack field type Select from ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

So, Im developing web app with Framework Laravel 5.3 include laravel-backpack and using php ver 5.6.30. I was trying use field type select2 from ajax in my app's field, but i got error that said my code have syntax error on 4bb1a9dc582e785d21cadb68014f51787068f3ed.php line 90.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCLSM.png)

Then i look to the file:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWq5S.png)

And my Controller is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;

// VALIDATION: change the requests to match your own file names if you need form validation
use App\Models\Report;
use App\Http\Requests\ReportRequest as StoreRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\ReportRequest as UpdateRequest;

class ReportCrudController extends CrudController
{

    public function setUp()
    {

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | BASIC CRUD INFORMATION
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */
        $this->crud->setModel("App\Models\Report");
        $this->crud->setRoute("admin/report");
        $this->crud->setEntityNameStrings('report', 'reports');

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | BASIC CRUD INFORMATION
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */

        //$this->crud->setFromDb();
        $this->crud->setColumns([

        [
        'label'     => "Student's Name", // Table column heading
        'type'      => 'select',
        'name'      => 'student', //-> on Question
        'entity'    => 'stackStudent', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model'     => 'App\Models\Student', // foreign key model
        ],

        [
        'label'     => 'Generation', // Table column heading
        'type'      => 'select',
        'name'      => 'generation', //-> on Question
        'entity'    => 'stackGeneration', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model'     => 'App\Models\Generation', // foreign key model
        ],

        [
        'label'     => 'Semester', // Table column heading
        'type'      => 'select',
        'name'      => 'semester', //-> on Question
        'entity'    => 'stackSemester', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model'     => 'App\Models\Semester', // foreign key model
        ],

        [
        'label'     => 'Class', // Table column heading
        'type'      => 'select',
        'name'      => 'class', //-> on Question
        'entity'    => 'stackClass', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model'     => 'App\Models\Kelas', // foreign key model
        ],

        [
        'label'     => 'Department', // Table column heading
        'type'      => 'select',
        'name'      => 'department', //-> on Question
        'entity'    => 'stackDepartment', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model'     => 'App\Models\Department', // foreign key model
        ],

        [
        'label'     => 'Class Type', // Table column heading
        'type'      => 'select',
        'name'      => 'classtype', //-> on Question
        'entity'    => 'stackClasstype', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model'     => 'App\Models\Classtype', // foreign key model
        ],

        [
        'label'     => 'Lesson', // Table column heading
        'type'      => 'select',
        'name'      => 'lesson', //-> on Question
        'entity'    => 'stackLesson', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model'     => 'App\Models\Lesson', // foreign key model
        ],
        [
        'name'  => 'score',
        'label' => 'Score',
        'type'  => 'number',
        ],


        ]);

        $this->crud->addFields([

        /*[
        'label'     => "Student's Name", // Table column heading
        'type'      => 'select',
        'name'      => 'student', //-> on Question
        'entity'    => 'stackStudent', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model'     => 'App\Models\Student', // foreign key model
        ],*/

        // 1-n relationship
        ['label' => "Student's Name", // Table column heading
        'type' => "select2_from_ajax",
        'name' => 'student', // the column that contains the ID of that connected entity
        'entity' => 'stackStudent', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => "name", // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model' => "App\Models\Student", // foreign key model
        'data_source' => url("api/student"), // url to controller search function (with /{id} should return model)
        'placeholder' => "Search a name...", // placeholder for the select
        'minimum_input_length' => 2, // minimum characters to type before querying results
        'pivit' => true,
        ],


        [
        'label'     => 'Generation', // Table column heading
        'type'      => 'select',
        'name'      => 'generation', //-> on Question
        'entity'    => 'stackGeneration', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model'     => 'App\Models\Generation', // foreign key model
        ],

        [
        'label'     => 'Semester', // Table column heading
        'type'      => 'select',
        'name'      => 'semester', //-> on Question
        'entity'    => 'stackSemester', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model'     => 'App\Models\Semester', // foreign key model
        ],

        [
        'label'     => 'Class', // Table column heading
        'type'      => 'select',
        'name'      => 'class', //-> on Question
        'entity'    => 'stackClass', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model'     => 'App\Models\Kelas', // foreign key model
        ],

        [
        'label'     => 'Department', // Table column heading
        'type'      => 'select',
        'name'      => 'department', //-> on Question
        'entity'    => 'stackDepartment', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model'     => 'App\Models\Department', // foreign key model
        ],

        [
        'label'     => 'Class Type', // Table column heading
        'type'      => 'select',
        'name'      => 'classtype', //-> on Question
        'entity'    => 'stackClasstype', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model'     => 'App\Models\Classtype', // foreign key model
        ],

        [
        'label'     => 'Lesson', // Table column heading
        'type'      => 'select',
        'name'      => 'lesson', //-> on Question
        'entity'    => 'stackLesson', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model'     => 'App\Models\Lesson', // foreign key model
        ],

        [
        'name'  => 'score',
        'label' => 'Score',
        'type'  => 'number',
        ],



        ]);



    }

    public function store(StoreRequest $request)
    {
        // your additional operations before save here
        $redirect_location = parent::storeCrud();
        // your additional operations after save here
        // use $this->data['entry'] or $this->crud->entry
        return $redirect_location;
    }

    public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
    {
        // your additional operations before save here
        $redirect_location = parent::updateCrud();
        // your additional operations after save here
        // use $this->data['entry'] or $this->crud->entry
        return $redirect_location;
    }
}
```

I do try fixing the code but fail. And finaly im end up here trying to get help from you guys. thank you for your attention.

Comment: You're trying to place PHP code into a javascript file. that won't work.

Comment: While it's not good practice, it shouldn't throw an error either. Show us the view where this happens. This is compiled cached view, find the original view. You're doing something along the lines of `$field['value'] ?? old($field['name']) ?? 0` somewhere. Which is incorrect php 5.6 syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the "null coalescing" operator `??` which is not available until PHP 7.